# Force authentication external website with Google Apps Domain

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-apps

Morning folks,

I need to implement a way to force authentication of people inside a Google Apps domain to access a website.

To be clear, an user try to get [site.com](https://my.website.com).
If he doesn't have a cookie, then he's redirected and forced to the Google OAuth2 login form.
If he has one, then he can visit the website.

In addition, the aim here is to restrict the login to only the users inside a Google Apps domain (people with other Google email adresses like Gmail won't work here).

I hope I was clear enough, thanks a lot in advance for your help guys ;)

Comment: I didn't get what's is your problem.... What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If the website is running on an Apache webserver, or you can front the website with an Apache web server operating as a reverse proxy, `mod_auth_openidc` (https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc) can enforce authentication with a Google Account and restrict it to a particular Google Apps domain, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc#openid-connect-sso-with-google-sign-in